# Proof question on how group homomorphisms preserve subgroup relationship

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have a question related to the following property of group homomorphisms.

> Let $f:G \rightarrow G'$ be a homomorphism between two groups. 
>  If $H'$ is a subgroup of $G'$, then $f^{-1}(H')$ is a subgroup of $G$

My question is: a homomorphism need not be bijective. Then can we in general talk about its inverse? My guess is that somehow restricting to the inverse image of the subgroup gives us an isomorphism, but cannot see it concretely. Appreciate the insight.

Comment: This is not an inverse function, this is the so called inverse image, or preimage. In general, if $f:A\to B$ is any function, and $C\subseteq B$ is a subset of $B$, then its inverse image is defined as $f^{-1}(C)=\{a\in A: f(a)\in C\}\subseteq A$. This has nothing to do with the function being invertible.

Comment: @Mark oh ok, thanks!